# Time Series Analysis with GAM for daily sales data

Tags: time-series, generalized-additive-model, seasonality, mgcv

I try to analyse the daily product demand of a warehouse which has five product categories.
The data is on a daily basis for 7 years. So I want to analyse the seasonal and cyclical patterns (day of week/month effects, holiday effects etc.) and want to do a week ahead forecast for each product category.First I tried a ARIMA regression approach with holiday lead and lag dummie variables but these results are not quite satisfactory in terms of MSE ore MAPE. For this reason I work now on a generalized additive model (GAM) with country specific holiday dummy variables. But at the moment I'm struggling because my results does look a bit confusing. Although, I have high R^2 (~80%) and also low MSE and MAPE my residuals look quite wired. So when I plot the residuals the QQ-plot and the density plot show that they are definitly are not normal distributed which they look in similar analysis.

[image]

I think that choosing a different family type by calling the gamm function could be one step to a better result. But how could I find the right one? I tried for instance the Gamma dist. which does not work because I have zero values in my response variable. At the moment this is the model I call:

```
model <- gamm(p1 ~ s(time_trend, by=year_trend) + te(day_num, month_num, k = c(7, 12), bs = c("cr", "cc")) + t2(day_num, week_num, k=c(7, 52), bs=c('cr', 'ps')) + 
              easter.mon + labor.day + new.year.day +  new.year.eve.lag + pentecost.lag1 + pent.monday +
              unity + xmas.day + xmas.day.lag2 + xmas.day.lag3 + xmas.day.lead2 + xmas.eve, data = train_matrix)
```

> where p1 is the daily log demand of my product category 1
> time trend is the numeric date which I divided by 1000 for scaling

my resulting plot looks like this

[image]

blue are my original values and red are the fitted ones.

I also included in another approach on the same model AR and MA terms but this also did not help much.

I hope someone can help me with this issue.
Best regards :)

Comment: Could you provide a graph of the fitted and forecast values vs actuals? I typically don't care so much about residuals when I just want predictive power for time series.

Comment: yes,  I have now added a plot of fitted vs actual values.

Comment: What is `year.trend`?

Comment: year.trend are the different years (e.g. for 2014 = 14) so that I would model for each year a trend. I read this post from you fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/09/… where you used all the dates as a time trend which I also included. When I used the by argument (which I seen in another post) I got better results than just using time_trend.